# Difference between （「~~~」と話した） and （「~~~」と語った）?

Tags: word-choice

In newspaper articles, quotes seem to be always followed by （「~~~」と **話した** ） and （「~~~」と **語った** ）.

*examples* :
大村明日香さんは「緊張しましたが、練習より楽しかった。大きな声を出すように心がけました」と **話した** 。 [(full context)](http://www.sankei.com/region/news/150505/rgn1505050029-n1.html)
担当者は「ますます女性にとって快適な機内にしたい」と **語った** 。 [(full context)](http://www.sankei.com/region/news/141205/rgn1412050080-n1.html)

What is the difference in meaning and usage between （「~~~」と **話した** ） and （「~~~」と **語った** ）?

Let me start by saying that（「~~~」と語った） is never used in conversation, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your examples, they're interchangeable. In general, 語る is only used when someone tells a story, opinion, idea, etc. You cannot use 語る when just おはよう or ごめん is said. In this case I think 語る is closer to *tell* and 言う is closer to *say*, because we can say 'say hello' but not 'tell hello'. (Of course the usage of *tell* and 語る are very different)

語る is safely used in conversations, but its colloquial use is probably limited to fairly long stories. "おじいちゃんが戦争の思い出を孫に語っているよ" is OK. Sometimes we can even just say "おじいちゃんがまた語り始めたよ", meaning "Grandpa stared his endless talk again!"